# Mysql addition and add them as new column

Tags: php, mysql, count, case

I want to fetch 2 coulmns count and do their total as a new column.
How can I do this?

i wrote this query, but this is returning wrong total.

```
SELECT count(case when `status`='1' then 1 else 0 end) AS HOT,
count(case when `status`='5' then 1 end) 
AS Special_Case,count(case when 1=1 then 1 end) AS TOTAL 
FROM `tbl_customer_conversation` group by 
date(`dt_added`),user_id
```

Comment: How do you mean by `do their total as new column`?

Comment: total count of numbers fetched in HOT and Special_Case

Comment: `case when 1=1 then 1 end` will always return one..

Comment: yes, but i want to get count of HOT, and Special_Case and then its total

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COUNT will only give the times a record is matched, which in your query will always return 1. Because the values can either  be `1` or `0`. So `count(1)` is also 1 and `count(0)` is also `1`.

AS, you want the total number of `HOT` cases and `SPECIAL_CASE` you have to use SUM.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(case when `status`='1' then 1 else 0 end) AS HOT,
    SUM(case when `status`='5' then 1 end) AS Special_Case,
    SUM(case when `status` = '1' or `status` = '5' then 1 end) AS TOTAL 
FROM `tbl_customer_conversation` 
group by date(`dt_added`),user_id
```

Comment: phpmyadmin says "#1305 - FUNCTION lmsapi.SUM does not exist "

Comment: @MohanSinfh, SUM does not allow spaces. I fixed the query try it again.

Comment: Would have upvoted this answer, if you had explained him why to use `SUM` and not `COUNT`